# How would you get the current time in Arm ASM using localtime()?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, arm, localtime

Im using a raspberry pi 3 and want to get the local computer time with localtime(), but I don' t how to go about it. My teacher tried to help me, but he didn't even know how to and ended doing the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main () {
   time_t rawtime;
   struct tm *info;
   time( &rawtime );
   info = localtime( &rawtime );
   printf("Current local time and date: %s", asctime(info));
   return(0);
}
```

and then just compiled into assembly, but I think that over complicated things and wanted to know if there was a more straight forward way of finding local time in arm assembly.
Thanks

Comment: Under Linux?  The raw system call is `clock_gettime`, but if the Pi 3 has a timesource that user-space can read directly, calling that via the VDSO is probably your best bat to avoid a switch from user to kernel and back   (The kernel exports a couple pages of code and data that contains user-space implementations of system calls like `getpid`.  The normal C library wrappers use it by default where appropriate.  Single-step into them with a debugger)

Answer (score 0):

In ARM Assembly, you can use the time syscall, or gettimeofday call (which returns Epoch) to retrieve the time, based on your requirement.

Comment: How would I be able to get the return value an put it into a register though? Or where does the value return, so I can mov it into a register I should say

Comment: @Zboyz: system-call return values are in `r0`.  Read about how to make ARM Linux system calls directly.  [What is the interface for ARM system calls and where is it defined in the Linux kernel?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12946958)

Comment: Yeah I was able to actually get the epoch time from r0 and store it someone where else. Now my new question is how would I convert it to just the current local time? I tried `strftime` , but got a segmentation fault.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I'm over simplifying the entire process to hopefully better answer your question; I hope I managed to convince you not to jump of a cliff and not just provide a non-answer answer :)

localtime() is a function provided by a C runtime library which usually ships together with the C compiler.
One of the steps the compiler performs when generating a runable program out of your C/C++ code is link to a C runtime library, so when your program needs to call a function, it will know where to find the dll/so file, load it into memory and give control to the required function. Most of the library load and described steps are performed by the operating system through well known functions (e.g. (dlopen)[https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen]).

You could write all that boilerplate, but you'd have to get a better understanding of the operating system and the C runtime, or you could just use your trusty c compiler and just get the code working.

If the goal of your task is to learn more about the ARM assembly language and the ARM processors, you should probably consult the processor's datasheet and see how it internally holds time.

Comment: No, dlopen is only used manually if don't specify the library at compile time.  Compile-time dynamic linking sets up the metadata so that happens for you automatically, and you can just `bl localtime@plt`, or in a non-PIE executable even just `bl localtime` and the linker really does take care of even creating a PLT and GOT for you.  It's really not hard to call libc functions from asm as long as you're writing a `main` and linking with `gcc`.  (And more complex or at least less safe if you're writing your own `_start` and linking manually with `ld`.)

Comment: What exactly would the code to ouput it with printf? Do I have to load some values in before a branch with localtime? Do I bl localtime, then bl printf? Thats really where the confusion is also coming from. How do I actually code this statement, and then use the result information. Can I store the number in a register after it is return etc.